# Drive API Permissions method: unclear behavior for anyoneWithLink permission

Tags: google-drive-api

I call the [Drive API Files:list method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) and request for the `permissions` field.

I notice a strange behavior; for some calls, I receive the following permission:

```json
{
 "kind": "drive#permission",
 "id": "anyoneWithLink",
 "type": "anyone",
 "role": "reader",
 "allowFileDiscovery": false
}
```

​But when I try to access the file associated with this permission, I get to the "Request Access" screen.

From the documentation, it seems like `anyoneWithLink` means the file should be publicly accessible.

What am I missing? What other information do I need to look at in order to know if the file is publicly accessible or not?

Comment: What scope are you using to authenticate the user?  or how are you trying to access the file?  can we see your code?

Comment: Using these scopes:
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.reports.audit.readonly',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly'

I'm trying to access the file from the value returned in the `webViewLink` field

Comment: okay how are you creating the anyoneWithLink?  anyoneWithLink  as far as i know anyoneWithLink can only be created though the website when you click the share button have you tried copying that link and using that.   This is not the same as webviewlink